# To split and display the string value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have api called `customer` which i am displaying in the `dropdown`, By choosing particular customer i am displaying that selected customer details(Properties of the selected **customer** object)(i,e phone,time) in the input fields like this:

[image]

The property **time** is an `string`, I want to split and display this string like this:

[image]

I am trying to splice it by **splice** method, But i am unable to achieve it.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-bap6tf?file=src/app/list/list.component.html)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your **list.component.html**
Try to use split like this.

```
<mat-form-field class="timings-days">
   <input matInput  placeholder="Hours" matInput [value]="customer?.time.split(':')[0]" >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field  class="timings-hrs">
   <input matInput  placeholder="Minutes" matInput [value]="customer?.time.split(':')[1]" >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field  class="timings-min">
   <input matInput  placeholder="Seconds" matInput [value]="customer?.time.split(':')[2]" >
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think better to use custom pipe rather than keeping your login in html. it may cause the issue. Broader way is to create custom pipe and keep your logic into separate file. Here how you can create your custom pipe.

**Pipe**:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timepart'
})
export class TimePartPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, part: string, symbol: string): string {
    if (symbol == "" || symbol == null) {
      symbol = ":";
    }
    var i = value.split(symbol);
    if (part == "hh")
      return i[0];
    if (part == "mm")
      return i[1];
    if (part == "ss")
      return i[2];
  }

}
```

**HTML**:
    // pass symbol and part which you want as argument

```
   <input matInput  placeholder="Hours" matInput [value]="customer?.timeArray[0]" >
</mat-form-field> -->
<mat-form-field  class="timings-hrs">
   <input matInput  placeholder="Minutes" matInput [value]="customer?.time | timepart : 'mm'" >
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field  class="timings-min">
   <input matInput  placeholder="Seconds" matInput [value]="customer?.time | timepart : 'ss'" >
```

This is more proper way to manipulate your HTML output.

**DEMO** : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-pvnwaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.html